How to print response in pdf file in android kotlin volley
In this screenshot response I have the form of a pdf file without url.
How to read the response in android kotlin using volley library
and show the pdf file as the response.
If I try to print it shows;
Error: "Value %PDF-1.3 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

Can any one help me with how to print the response as pdf file?
